2015 or 2016 movie of a woman/science experiment who destroys her lab/confinement
I'm trying to find out the name of a movie I saw the trailer for but never got a chance to see.  In the trailer I think there is a young woman who seems to be an experiment of some sort - she's powerful and deadly.  The trailer shows standard plot of her getting out of control, killing people, and I think someone (the main character) goes in to try to talk/control her.
It's not Splice, since that movie is older and in that movie she turns out to be an actual monster of some sort.  In this movie I don't think she has any mutations that I can remember.

I'm almost certain the movie you're talking about is called "Morgan" ! 

OPE nevermind just realized you already found out XD lol

It is OK to simply delete your answer. You can also delete a comment.

Could it be Lucy (2014) with Scarlett Johansson?
When a boyfriend tricks Lucy (Scarlett Johansson) into delivering a briefcase to a supposed business contact, the once-carefree student is abducted by thugs who intend to turn her into a drug mule. She is surgically implanted with a package containing a powerful chemical, but it leaks into her system, giving her superhuman abilities, including telekinesis and telepathy. With her former captors in pursuit, Lucy seeks out a neurologist (Morgan Freeman), who she hopes will be able to help her.

I just found it, it's called Morgan - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4520364/

Could it be Ex Machina? (released in 2015)
In the movie Alicia Vikander plays a robot in the shape of a young woman (sometimes looking like a young woman, sometimes deliberately looking like a robot) who is part of a rich billionaire's attempt to create an artificial intelligence. She is part of an experiment to see whether she can develop human characteristics when interacting with a human subject. The human subject is also, unknowingly, part of the experiment (or, perhaps, a part of it without knowing the full scope or intention of the experiment).
Late in the movie she proves to be powerful and deadly, getting out of control in unexpected ways, killing people and destroying parts of the laboratory.
BTW the trailer shows some of this but not in a way that reveals the plot or the ending leaving viewers somewhat surprised at how the movie plays out.

I liked Ex Machina, but the movie I was thinking of is more recent - turns out it's called Morgan http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4520364/

@MonkeyBonkey you threw me on timing: Morgan has only just been released and is still in theatres.
